# bash script reading an RSS feed and execute another script if result is greater than X

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, while-loop

I'm a bit messed up with while read and If routines.

I'm trying to create a bash script for Linux which reads the processed clean numerical output from rsstail and if the numerical output is greater than 5.5 then it executes another script I already have.

The main command for rsstail I'm running is checking for the newest RSS every 3 seconds and gets the first clean 3-5 characters which are the numbers I need, using the following:

```
rsstail -i 3 -u http://someserver/somefile.xml -n 1 -N | cut -c 3-5
```

The output of that is a single number like

```
3.7
```

Then I need to compare constantly the numerical output and IF it is greater than 5.5, then execute another script I already have. If it is not, do nothing but continue to check the rsstail output for values greater than 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, pipe your output i.e. single line with value like

```
3.7
```

into

```
awk '{if($1>5.5){system("bash yourscript.sh")}}'
```

This will do `bash yourscript.sh` if condition is meet else it will do nothing. Keep in mind that [system](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html) *Execute the operating system command command and then return to the awk program. Return command’s exit status*

Comment: I get a syntax error at if

Comment: @lefleflef I fixed my code, please check if it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Since you are performing a numerical test with floating numbers, you could invoke `bc` to do the job.

Try

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  output=$(rsstail -i 3 -u http://someserver/somefile.xml -n 1 -N | cut -c 3-5)
  condition=$(echo "($output - 5.5) > 0" | bc)
  if [ "$condition" -eq 1 ]
    then echo "executing other script"
  fi
  sleep 3
done
```

Comment: I get line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: Adding `;` after `while true` resolved the syntax error, sorry.